# Namespace not found when adding Xamarin.iOS binding to small sample app

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am with a company that distributes a Swift/Objective-C framework for iOS and Android.

I'm trying to get a Xamarin.iOS binding library up and working - I have the iOS binding solution together and it seems to compile OK.

However, when I try to include that binding project into a small sample app to test, it seems like the sample app is unable to see the namespace of by binding and/or framework.

Included below, is what the project structure looks like - I added the binding project to the sample app project, then also added the binding as a reference for the application.  I also included the Xamarin.swift package from Nuget as the framework is Swift5 based.

[image]

Here's where I'm trying to include the framework namespace with Using, that gives an error compiling - the funny thing is I see warnings in the compilation from the binding project, so it seems like the project has been included correctly.

[image]

I am pretty inexperienced to Xamarin, so there is no item too basic I may have overlooked in adding the Nami binding project to this sample app.

In case it makes any difference, I only have the iOS side of the binding project in place, the sample app is iOS and Android but I'm just trying to run the iOS side and have not modified the Android side.

The framework I am binding to is a fat framework that has no external dependancies, using only Foundation, UIKit and StoreKit internally.

If anyone wants to take a look at the project, I included the sample app and binding project in this zip file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kgl2d86s2ehmxck/BindingToSampleApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: you can't use an iOS binding library from a shared Forms project.  You can only use it in the iOS project.

Comment: and please do not post code as images

Comment: @Jason: I normally feel the same way you do about code as image, however in this case it's not really the code that is in question, but the project configuration - posting code would not show the error indication on "using Nami;".  I think I get what you are saying about project being included at a higher level than it should be, although I just include it at the top level and then actually add the reference to it in the iOS portion of the project specifically, as you can see in the SmpleApp.ios->Refrerences section which includes NamiSDKComboBinding.

Comment: Come to think of it, since the binding is suppose to be for IOS and Android eventually, wouldn't I want a project at the top level still?  Or would I make separate bindings for iOS and Android?  The instructions I read in various places seem to indicate they should be combined.

Comment: That is not how XF works.  You have a "head" project for each platform, and a common project (typically .NET Standard) that contains shared code that runs on all platforms.  You need a separate binding library for each platform, because you JAVA library will not run on iOS, and your iOS library will not run on Android.  For your purposes, it may make more sense to create separate Android and iOS projects than to use XF.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a **separate** solution that contains **only** the Native Binding project.

And add it as a nuget or dll link in other projects.